# What are the most comprehensive examples of businesses making strategy, marketing and performance data publicly available?

Tags: data-request, finance, business

Everpix recently gave an interesting look (https://github.com/everpix/Everpix-Intelligence) into the shuttered startup by providing everything from pitch decks to website analytics and subscription revenue data. A more intimate look than what you would see in SEC filings or quarterly earnings. What other companies, startup or established, have provided such an in-depth look at the business?